# Overlapping Area chart ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

seeking help with creating stacked graph in R.

Example data:

```
Brand <- c('A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A, 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A'') 
Month<- c( 'January', 'January', 'March', 'February', 'April', 'Spetember', 'May', 'July', 'June', 'November', 'December', 'October', 'August')             
Value <- runif(13, 0.0, 30.0)      
data <- data.frame(Brand , Month, Value)
```

Here is what I was capable of making:

```
ggplot(data,
                      aes(x = Month,
                          y = Value,
                          group = Brand,
                          fill = Brand)) +
        geom_area() +
  expand_limits( x = c(0,NA), y = c(0,NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Brand"))
```

[image]

And here is desired outcome (made in excel):
[image]

We would like to see the values of all brand in time, as showed on excel chart.
Any ideas how to achieve similar outcome with ggplot in R?

Thanks to any idea in advance

Comment: Are you looking for `position ="identity"` inside `geom_area`?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes! Thank you. only thing now is, that there are some brands with smaller values, which are overlaid by those with bigger values. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes! Thank you. only thing now is, that there are some brands with smaller values, which are overlaid by those with bigger values. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what the question asks for.
`geom_area`'s default position is `position="stack"`, therefore the areas shouldn't be covering other areas drawn first. So, I believe that the problem is with incomplete data, meaning, no data for certain combinations of brand and month. The code below uses `tidyr::complete` to fill in those values with zeros and then plots the transformed data.

**Note:** In the posted data, there was a repetition of brand `"A"` in January. I have changed the 2nd brand to `"B"`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})
  
set.seed(2022)
Brand <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A') 
Month<- c( 'January', 'January', 'March', 'February', 'April', 'September', 
           'May', 'July', 'June', 'November', 'December', 'October', 'August')             
Value <- runif(13, 0.0, 30.0)      
data <- data.frame(Brand , Month, Value)

data %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  complete(Month = month.name, 
           fill = list(Value = 0)) %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = month.name)) %>%
  arrange(Brand, Month) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(x = Month, y = Value, group = Brand, fill = Brand)
  ) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "#5f7530", B = "#772c2a", C = "#4bacc6")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Brand")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Looking your data. I can see that you have unique values between Month and Brand. Namely, you won't have in the same Month for more than one Brand category.

I have plotted your data with transparency to can look it issue using your code.
But I have order the Month vector so that it can plotted in chronological order instead alphabetical default.

```
level_order <- c("January", "February", "March",  "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Spetember", "October", "November", "December") # order Month chronological

ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(Month, level = level_order), y = Value,
             group = Brand,
             fill = Brand)) + 
xlab("Month") + 
geom_area(alpha = 0.5) + 
expand_limits( x = c(0,NA), y = c(0,NA)) + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Brand"))
```

[image: Plot result with your data]